# Who is the "guy" Kabal is referring to?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), Shang Tsung prepares his warriors to kill Earthrealm's champions:

> Shang Tsung: Raiden has prevented entry into his temple. I must find a
> way to bring his shield down in order to obliterate our opposition.
>
> Kabal: I think I can help. Did you see **a guy** down there? A
> complete fu*king as*hole. Answers to Kano.

Who is the "guy" Kabal is referring to?

Comment: “I think I can help. Did you see a Guy down there? A complete f——— a———. Answers to ‘Smiley.’”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's referring to Kano. When he says "Answers to Kano", that's a shortened way of saying that the person he's talking about answers *to the name of* 'Kano'. Which is a way of saying that that person *responds* to the name of 'Kano' (when it is spoken *to* them), because that is in fact their name.

[Answer to the name of - Idioms by The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/answer+to+the+name+of)

Also, Kabal keeps talking about Kano right afterwards, so Kano is clearly the person on his mind, and they (Kabal and Kano) clearly have a history of animosity toward one another.

> SHANG TSUNG: My loyal warriors, Kabal, General Reiko, I have seen the so-called champions of Earth realm, and they’re no match for all of you. We are on the precipice of victory and taking Earth realm forever. But we must strike now. Raiden has prevented entry into his temple. I must find a way to bring his shield down in order to obliterate our opposition.
>
> KABAL: I think I can help. **Did you see a guy down there? A complete fucking asshole. Answers to Kano.**
>
> SHANG TSUNG: **Kano.**
>
> KABAL: **Yeah. He’s the reason I live in an iron lung. He’s a low life, piece of shit scumbag. You’re going to love him.**
>
> <sub>*Mortal Kombat* (2021)</sub>